# Fatal Error V8 Array Buffer NewBackingStore Allocatation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-flex

We are encountering process out of memory error when running twilio flex:plugins:deploy command to deploy the plugin code. I have reached out to Twilio team and they have mentioned that is a node.js error. I have increased the memory size of node by configuring this in the windows environment variable. Node version on my machine is v16.20.0

**node --max-old-space-size=1024**

I have attached the error message too, Please let us know on how to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance

[image]